# How to pass form data from angular ui bootstrap modal to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I'm creating a webapp and I want to implement an option to add friends. I've created the add friend page as a modal with a text input field. I want to test this by displaying the input on my view page. How do I display this data onto my view page?

Here's what I currently have

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>

         <form name = "addFriendForm">
          <input ng-model = "user.name"class="form-control" type = "text" placeholder="Username" title=" Username" />
          {{ user.name }}
        </form>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Add Friend</button>
    <div> Username: {{user.name}}</div>
</div>
```

my JavaScript file:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.user = {name: ""}

  $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function () {
      $scope.user.name = user.name;}, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
});

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.user.name);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/JIoiNx47KXsY8aqbTUDS?p=preview

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Resolve - [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eZLtGY?p=preview)

You could make use of `modalInstance`'s `resolve` property; this acts as the link between the modal instance and the parent controller.

You inject the object in to the `ModalInstanceController`, and assign it to the scope of your modal instance.

UI Bootstraps resolve works exactly the same as ngRouter's; as such if for whatever reason `resolve` cannot *resolve* an object, the modal will not open.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  resolve: {
    user: function() {
      return $scope.user;
    }
  }
});
```

### Scope - [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xyOSVrxLnAtSpjZ8kdlm?p=preview)

An alternative, and arguably simpler method would be to pass in the parents scope in to the modal. Note that currently this doesn't work when using `controllerAs` syntax on the parent controller.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  scope: $scope
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the promise from the result to set the value to your controller's variables instead.  The "resolve" from my understanding is for passing controller's variable to the dialog for using inside the dialog, not to be changed directly.  In your code example, passing result you set in $modalInstance.close() to modalInstance.result.then() will do the trick. In other words, changing line #18 and #19 to the following,

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
$scope.user.name = data;
```

To improve the code a bit, you can actually pass the entire user object to allow adding additional attributes such as email, address, etc. to your user object easily.  I had create an example at http://plnkr.co/edit/oztYRNrCRlF1Pw289i1M?p=preview.